# Cannot import JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, import, export

I try to import a js class and use its inner function. When I do this my page won't load due to an unknown error in the import line (when I remove the line page gets loaded).

The class:

```
export default class BombsMap {
    constructor (block) {
        this.block = block;
    }

    get bombsPlacing() {
        // irrelevant code
        return this.block;
    }

    static nearBombUpdate(rnd_i, rnd_j) {
        // irrelevant code
    }
}
```

The code from file2:

```
import BombsMap from './BombsMap';
const inst = new BombsMap(block);
```

I've tried to import only the function, to change the link to './BombsMap.js', and to import BombsMap with brackets such as { BombsMap }. None of these worked.

Comment: Are you running this script from a server or a local server? What kind of error are you having? If you have a CORS error, it's due to ES6 modules are subject to same-origin policy, and you should run your code into a server or disable the same-origin in the browser

Answer (score 1):

Check, really your file (immediately file, because in path you put path to *file*, not a *function*) named *BombsMap* in import:

```
import BombsMap from './BombsMap';
```

Comment: The file I want to import to called 'app.js', the export file indeed named 'BombsMap.js'. The line you purposed is the code I try to import with, which doesn't work.